# Send type into function using templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have this function for finding key in map and return the right value with type:

```
template< typename T >
T Foo::findInMap(std::string key) {
    std::map<std::string, std::any>::iterator it = options.find(key);
    if (it != options.end())
    {
        return std::any_cast<T>(it->second);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

the map looks like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::any> options;
```

How can I call and modify the function to get the best out of C++17?

Comment: This is not C++17 but "C++98": You maybe could give a the address of a standard constructed T variable into the lookup function instead of returning it by value. So a bool return could be used instead of `nullptr` which will also not work because of the current return type spec (maybe typo?).

Comment: `std::optional` is C++17

Comment: it is not code review , im new to c++17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning a `nullptr` is not always possible. Modern C++ way of returning optional values is to use `std::optional`. You can use `auto` instead of the long iterator type name. Here's one way you can do it:

```cpp
template< typename T >
std::optional<T> findInMap(std::string key) {
    auto const it = options.find(key);
    if (it != options.end())
        return std::optional<T>{ std::any_cast<T>(it->second) };
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how this would be called?

Comment: If one wants to go "full C++17" then CTAD for `std::optional` is also possible. And `it` can be defined in the `if`'s optional init statement.

Comment: Great thanks. While I still think this could not harm your answer if included :-)

Answer (score 3):

For simultaneous declaration and initialization, [std::optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66041677/2932052) may offer the superior approach. But type variability and optionality take their toll on context (read: invocation and case distinctions) in any case. I decided to take the cost of loading the surrounding scope with a variable that is default-initialized to be overwritten afterwards in the found case. This way I get a function call whose argument determines the type, making the type specification in angle brackets unnecessary for the caller.

I also renamed the function into `map_assign` (removed the member function status since irrelevant here):

```
template< typename T >
bool map_assign(const std::string& key, T* value) {
    auto it = options.find(key);
    if (it != options.end())
    {
        *value = std::any_cast<T>(it->second);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
std::string value;
if (map_assign("somekey", &value)) {
    // found case
} else {
    // not-found case
}
```

Comment: Thanks , why pointer in the any_cast? i can return by ref without the pointer just fine

Comment: Thank you, there was also an issue that I fixed. I could have implemented it by reference, but that's just a stylistic detail, and having personally gone through a heavily reference-oriented phase, I'm currently leaning more towards the pointer version.

Answer (score 0):

any_cast(T&) throws **std::bad_any_cast**, use any_cast(const T*) instead

```cpp
struct Test {
  template <typename T>
  std::optional<T> findInMap(std::string key) {
    if (auto it = options.find(key); it != options.end()) {
      if(auto ptr = std::any_cast<T>(&it->second); ptr) {
        return std::make_optional<T>(*ptr);
      }
    }
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  std::map<std::string, std::any> options;
};
```