# Stop bycatch of <stdio.h> definitions caused by C++ includes

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, std, stdio

In a comment to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66041677/2932052), I was shown a [code example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/evcEef) that seemingly used `printf` and `puts` without including `<stdio.h>` but the online compiler didn't complain.<sup>[1]</sup> To understand what's going on, I copied it to my local IDE.

Reduced to relevant includes and output, it's basically this:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <optional>

int main() {
  printf("Answer %d\n", 42);
  puts("Question?");
}
```

Experimenting with gcc 8.1.0 (packaged with Clode::Blocks 20.03), I found out, that the includes can be further reduced to

- `<string>` or `<map>` or `<optional>` in C++17 (ISO/GCC)
- `<string>` or `<map>` in C++11/C++14 (ISO/GCC)
- `<string>` in C++98 (ISO/GCC)

Also a sample test - [C++14 (gcc 8.3) - on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/jmisTD) compiles and runs fine:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    printf("printf without #include <stdio.h>\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is also true for other definitions from `<stdio.h>` like `FILE`.

I found no information at cppreference.com

- [std::printf, std::fprintf, std::sprintf, std::snprintf - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)
- [std::puts - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/puts)
- [printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf, printf_s, fprintf_s, sprintf_s, snprintf_s - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)
- [puts - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts)

I also tried several web and SO searches but wasn't successful so far.

While it *may* be handy for small examples to get some powerful functions for free, but a serious project may suffer from it: besides comparatively easy to fix compiler errors, I see the danger of serious runtime errors.

**How can I effectively control/prevent this kind of inclusion?**

---

<sup>[1]</sup> the referenced code now contains the include statement, but I'm pretty sure that it didn't at stage I copied it .. or maybe I copied just a portion of it? ... anyway the observed behavior is there as described above.

Comment: `How can I effectively control/prevent this kind of inclusion?` The only good "effective" solution is to write your own C++ standard library that does that and does not include C header files. The behavior is valid - standard headers are allowed to include themselves.

Comment: I have found this:


`-nostartfiles`  

`Do not use the standard system startup files when linking. The standard system libraries are used normally, unless -nostdlib, -nolibc, or -nodefaultlibs is used.`
 `https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot.

The standard requires that the well known include files declare the relevant names, but does not prevent them to include other files/names, if the library implementation finds it useful.

Said differently, after including `iostream` you are sure that all the names belonging to it are correctly declared, but you cannot know (except by examining the file itself) if other names have been defined, or if other standard files have been included. Here, your implementation chooses to automatically include `stdio.h`, but a different (standard library) implementation could choose not to include it. You have reached the world of *unspecifiedness*...

Comment: So it's not possible to find a reference that tells me which C headers would be included by which C++ headers? I mean complaining may be quite pointless for the `<iostream>` `printf` combination but what about `<map>` introducing `fseek`?

Comment: Yes, that's what he said.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from any arguments about "purity", I don't see how including the declarations for these functions could in any way be harmful. As a matter of fact, *not* having them and letting the compiler implicitly assuming `int printf()` – albeit only C compilers do it, C++ won't – is calling for trouble.

`printf` is part of the C language standard. And although C++ isn't C, there's so much overlap between their ecosystems, that C++ considers `printf` as part of the implementation runtime environment as well, as it does with all the other functions from the C standard library.

And as such, all of these symbols are *reserved*. Outside of actually implementing the runtime library itself, you have no business defining symbols of those names yourself.

`#include` preprocessor directives are just inline text substitution with text pulled in from an additional file.

(`extern`) symbol *declarations* will not create symbols of those names, but they will make sure, that you're not going to *redefine* those symbols at your own.

So I really don't see where your worries about runtime errors do come from.

Comment: Can you maybe include a reference for the `reserved` words?

Comment: @Wolf: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf section "Index of library names"

Comment: @Wolf: In short: Each and every identifier in global scope or the `std::` namespace that's specified in the C++ language standard is reserved. *You must not use it* for anything you define yourself. However in C++ namespaces matter and you can use them, if you put them under a custom namespace.

Comment: Thanks. I know that namespaces are relevant (as well for the linker) and also that I should keep out of the `std` namespace. What I ask about is "naked C symbols" in the global namespace at compile time (for reasons that in some cases seem completely absurd). I understand that there is a need to allow C++ standard library implementers to build on the C lib, and in this case, it absolutely makes sense to introduce these names as to catch clashes already at compile time. But why on earth does `#include <optional>` introduce I/O functions?

Comment: Because those identifiers specified by the C language standard are inherited by the C++ language standard, defined to live in the global namespace, and are explicitly defined to exist and live there since almost forever. `#include <cmath>`, `#include <cstdio>` and such are well defined within the C++ language standard and for all intents and purposes fully import the whole set of C reserved identifiers (including all the ruled on reservations for future used, like `::is…` being reserved for the language implementation).